# Multiple Search of QUERY + PLACE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, mongoid

I am trying to create a search for a specific model called Location with indexes:

```
mapping do
  indexes :_id, :as => "_id.to_s", :index => "not_analyzed"
  indexes :name, analyzer: 'english'
  indexes :address, analyzer: 'english', type: :string
  indexes :country, type: :string
  indexes :city, type: :string
  indexes :province, type: :string
  indexes :state, type: :string
  indexes :postalcode, type: :string
  indexes :latlng, type: :geo_point, lat_lon: true
end
```

The specific search must be like this:

> http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Mezban+11&place=panchkula

where "Mezban 11" is the name of the Location and "panchkula" is the city of the Location.

The search must include NAME as a priority, CITY as second priority and ADDRESS, COUNTRY, PROVINCE, STATE, POSTALCODE as last priority.

This is the actual query i am testing:

```
search_name = Location.search({
      query: {
          bool: {
              should: [
                  {
                      multi_match: {
                          query: "#{query}",
                          fields: ['name^5'],
                          type: 'best_fields'
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      multi_match: {
                          query: "#{place}",
                          fields: ['address', 'city'],
                          operator: 'and'
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  })
```

But this query brings me "Mezban 11 in Panchkula" as a 3er item in the query, and should be 1st because i am searching for a specific Location that live in my DataBase.

**How should i create the query in elasticsearch to search in diferents fields but setting priority to the name of the Location?**

Comment: Did you run the query also with explain to see, which match causes the weird scoring?

Comment: Dont know how to do that... sorry @MichaelStockerl...

Comment: I'm no Ruby Developer but this link should show you how ;) http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch/API/Actions#explain-instance_method